# Count distint while using clause over

Tags: google-bigquery

i have to find solution for counting distint users in BigQuery in last for example 30 days. My results are not event close to what i get from Google Analytics.

I made subquery with distinct users in next step i was selecting results as Active_Users_28_Days from subquery (from (select...) where i was counting the numbers of unique visitors visiting website during past 28 days (like part of query below), but my results are way to high and i can not figure why.

COUNT(Visitors) OVER (PARTITION BY Date ORDER BY Date ROWS BETWEEN 27 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as Active_Users_28_Days

Do you have idea why it count be like that? I also want to calculate specific type of clients using similar way, but i don't know why my results are to high event calculating 2 days (ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW or ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW - both gives wrong results when i compare then to separate results of sql query with grouping by just Date) .

Answer (score 0):

You are counting users, not distinct users.Try `COUNT(DISTINCT Visitors)` instead.

Comment: Cant put distinct directly into count while using over. Thats the point of this post. I created temp table with subquery with distinct users in the previous step.

Comment: strange... there is an example in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#count)